# Как в js при переходе по ссылке передать параметры меню?

Tags: javascript

Вот написано меню, в котором 2 списка (длина и ширина), которые в начальном положении скрыты, но они открываются при нажатии на них а при переходе по ссылке выбранного пункта - закрываются в дефолтное положение (отрабатывает $("ul").hide();). Как сделать, чтоб при переходе открытость или закрытость меню передавалась в js коде?

Вот ссылка на jsfiddle (для общего представления):
http://jsfiddle.net/Alexboo/nh3jutfb/3/

Файл css:

```
.box {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;      
}
h3 span {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.line {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Файл html:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
    <h3>Длина:<span class="expand">+</span></h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="..."></a>1 метр</li>
          <li><a href="..."></a>2 метра</li>
          <li><a href="..."></a>3 метра</li>
        </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>Ширина:<span class="expand">+</span></h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="..."></a>1 метр</li>
          <li><a href="..."></a>2 метра</li>
          <li><a href="..."></a>3 метра</li>                                       
        </ul>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").hide();     // Эта строка прячет список
    $(".box h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        var text = $("span",this).text();
        $("span",this).text(text != "+" ? "+" : "-")
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал через GET параметр, допустим при переходе генерируешь 'www.example.com?menu=1', и в коде прописуешь в js
парсилку GET запроса

```
function $_GET(key) {
    var s = window.location.search;
    s = s.match(new RegExp(key + '=([^&=]+)'));
    return s ? s[1] : false;
}
```

и потом ифами выбираешь состояния меню.
Расширенный пример:

```
?menu=11 = Выбраны пункты 1,1
?menu=12 = Выбраны пункты 1,2
?menu=13 = Выбраны пункты 1,3
```

И так далее...

Comment: Anton, спасибо, сейчас разбираюсь с Вашим кодом...мне не нужно передавать выбранный пункт (я это по-другому реализую), мне нужно передать заменить строку $("ul").hide(); , которая на новой странице не закрывало бы меню, как по дефолту! Например, открыта длина, закрыта ширина - так и передало, а не позакрывало , как прописано по дефолту строкой $("ul").hide();

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var menu = $_GET(page);
      if(menu == '') $("ul").hide(); // если первый раз - menu пустое - скрываем

      // $("ul").hide(); тут убираем
        $(".box h3").click(function(){
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            var text = $("span",this).text();
            $("span",this).text(text != "+" ? "+" : "-")
        });
    });

function $_GET(key) {
    var s = window.location.search;
    s = s.match(new RegExp(key + '=([^&=]+)'));
    return s ? s[1] : false;
}
```

Comment: при написании функции $_GET(key) перестает срабатывать $(this).next().slideToggle(), т.е. меню не закрывается